# Greatest-n-per-group rails ActiveRecord SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, greatest-n-per-group

I have a `ActiveRecord` model `Post` that contains the fields `created_at` and `score`. I want to order the `Posts` by score in the last 50 ones created. So basically the SQL would be

```
SELECT * FROM
(SELECT * FROM Posts ORDER BY created_at DESC LIMIT 50) Sorted_Posts
ORDER BY score DESC
```

Unfortunately I'm not sure how to do this in Rails. I prefer not to use raw SQL to accomplish this since there's many filters other stuff in the query not shown that would really complicate the raw SQL. I looked into perhaps using the `to_sql` and strip the `SELECT * FROM POSTS` prefix out then put it in a `where` or `find_by_sql` function but I feel like this could be hacky and potentially lead to SQL injections?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe something like this:

`Order.where(id: Order.order(:created_at => :desc).limit(50).ids).order(:score => :desc)`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Post.order('created_at DESC').limit(50).order('score DESC')
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but I tried this and according to the docs, it follows the standard model on SQL queries. So what it produces is actually `SELECT * FROM Posts ORDER BY created_at DESC, score DESC LIMIT 50`

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this would work for your use case, but it's one way to accomplish what you're asking

```
Post.from("(#{Post.order('created_at DESC').limit(50).to_sql}) posts").order('score DESC')
```

Essentially, you're building the inner query then converting it into an SQL literal and using interpolation to get that into the from portion of the outer query.